# Sql query - get all matching records and remaining records in left table

Tags: sql

I am new to sql please assist.

Table test1:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

table test2:

```
ID STATUS
1   DONE
2   FAILED
```

I need resultset as below (all rows in test1 that match the condition as well as all IDs not in test2, condition is status !='DONE')

```
2
3
```

I can easily get output as 2 or 1,2,3 using left join, inner join etc But getting 2,3 is a challenge. Please assist. Please note above is a sample data. Forgive formatting mistakes as  posting via mobile, cannot post from browser in office.

Comment: Isn't all rows in `test1` combined with all rows which did not match `test1` the same as every row?

Comment: Added the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ID` is the primary key in both tables, you can use left outer join, and ask for rows where the *outer* `id` column is `NULL`:

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM test1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
WHERE t2.STATUS <> 'Done' OR t2.ID IS NULL
```

Left part of the `OR` condition is your original `WHERE` clause; right side adds rows *not* matched in `test2`.

Comment: This would not work if an `id` could have more than one status in `test2` (and one was done and another not done).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I assume that ID is a primary key in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You want all ids from `test1` that are not "DONE" in `test2`.  I recommend `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t1.id
from test1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from test2 t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.status = 'DONE'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.